# How do I put a html tag conditional in jade?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, node.js, pug

In [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade), I want to put in a html tag conditional as per [this method](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/), which puts in

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

at the top of a html file.

I tried

```
//[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]
//[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]
//[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]
//[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]
  head
    ...
```

but jade ignores the html tag, and doesn't write in the end `</html>` tag. This is invalid html, and results in IE not displaying anything at all.

Is there any way of doing it?

I'm thinking I'll just use a javascript solution if there isn't a way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>This method works, with the closing html tag:</strike>

```
!!! 5
//if lt IE 7
    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7">
//if IE 7
    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8">
//if IE 8
    <html class="no-js lt-ie9">
// [if gt IE 8] <!
html(class="no-js", lang="en")
    // <![endif]
    head
        title= title

    body!= body
```

from: https://gist.github.com/kmiyashiro/1140425#comment-675550

Update:

As pointed out by [kumar-harsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630170/kumar-harsh) this behaviour has now been depreciated, if you need this functionality you now should use regular html:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <html class="ie">
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
  <html class="not-ie">
<![endif]>
</html>
```

from: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1345?source=cc#issuecomment-31920732

Comment: do note that this functionality has been deprecated in jade 1.0.0.

Now you have to write plain old HTML comments. [See this issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1345?source=cc)

Comment: Thanks Kumar, I've updated the answer to prevent any confusion.

Answer (score 17):

This is what you're looking for, and it will also give the closing html tag.

```
!!! 5
//[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js oldie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]
//[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js oldie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]
//[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js oldie lt-ie9"><![endif]
//[if gt IE 8]><!
html(class='no-js', lang='en')
  //<![endif]
  head
```

Comment: I think this is the appropriate reply because those conditional appear as comments, rather than clean read code. Also, you get the html closing tag.

Comment: This works perfectly for me with closing `html` tag. No need to look any further. The only change I would make is that the `!!! 5` doctype declaration is no longer supported. Instead, use `doctype html`. See http://jade-lang.com/reference/doctype/

Answer (score 11):

Simply use this syntax, mind the different indentation:

```
!!! 5
| <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
| <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
| <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
| <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
head
  …
```

Comment: Do you get a closing </HTML> tag?

Answer (score 8):

In version `1.0.0` (released on **22 December 2013**) Jade does not parse comments content any more and support for the IE conditional comments has been removed (`//if lt IE 7` will not work as in version `0.35.0` and below).

The new approach is to use well formatted IE conditional comments. So in order to generate above IE conditional comments, Jade template will have to be as follows:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
html(class="") 
  <!--<![endif]-->
  ...
```

Note that the first four `html` elements are well formatted HTML elements. The last one uses Jade syntax. Also the last comment `<!--<![endif]-->` has to be indented.

With Jade version 1.0.0 and above it is safe to use HTML comments as Jade will ignore any line beginning with `<` character.

You can also visit [this post](http://tompawlak.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/ie-conditional-comments-in-jade_1.html) on IE Conditional Comments in Jade which talks about difference between Jade version `0.35.0` and `1.0.0`. It also shows alternative approach of using Jade mixins mechanism for conditional comments.

Answer (score 3):

Starting at version 1.0.0, the `// if` construct [is not magical anymore](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1345?source=cc#issuecomment-31920732). Either render HTML verbatim (any line starting with < is transmitted as-is by Jade) or use a mixin, as per [Tom's blog](http://blog.tompawlak.org/ie-conditional-comments-jade) cited in another answer:

```
mixin ie(condition)
    | <!--[!{condition}]>
    block
    | <![endif]-->

doctype html
html
  head
    title= My title
    +ie('if IE 8')
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style-ie8-1.css')
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

Exemple:

**HTML**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

**JADE**

```
//[if lt IE 7]>
  <html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]
//[if IE 7]>
  <html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]
//[if IE 8]>
  <html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]
```

Answer (score -5):

as far as i know you can not put html tags like this in jade. for this either you need to include an html or by using trailing (.) in tags which supports text like:

```
p. <html><script></script>....
```

So html tag does not support text so you cant do it. the other solution is:

```
-if IE==6
    html.ie6
-if IE==7
    html.ie7
-if IE==8
    html.ie8
-if IE==9
    html.ie9
  head
  body
      h1 My sit
```

Comment: IE is not defined as a variable and you've not declared it in your answer.